# JBoss EAP 6.4: NoClassDefFound in windows but not on Linux

Tags: classloader, jboss-eap-6

I have same EAR deployed in JBoss EAP 6.4 in windows and linux env. I am getting below exception in windows but not in linux.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/bp/gp/addfilters/CMnAddQueryConverter
at com.bp.dw.sales.datacache.CMnDataCacheHelper.getDataSourceCriterion(CMnDataCacheHelper.java:649)
com.bp.dw.sales.datacache.CMnDataCacheHelper.applyFiltersToDataCache(CMnDataCacheHelper.java:429)
com.bp.dw.sales.datacache.CMnDataCacheHelper.applyFiltersToDataCache(CMnDataCacheHelper.java:407)
com.bp.dw.sales.datacache.CMnBaseDataCacheMgr.initiateDataCachePopulate(CMnBaseDataCacheMgr.java:211)
com.bp.dw.sales.datacache.CMnPopulateDataCacheCommand.execute(CMnPopulateDataCacheCommand.java:199)
at com.bp.gp.wb.CMnWorkbookPriceCommand.executeUnit(CMnWorkbookPriceCommand.java:76)
com.bp.dw.sales.datacache.pool.CMnDataCachePoolMgr.spawnCache(CMnDataCachePoolMgr.java:628)
com.bp.dw.sales.datacache.pool.CMnDataCachePoolMgr.processCache(CMnDataCachePoolMgr.java:571)
com.bp.dw.sales.datacache.pool.CMnDataCachePoolMgr.processCache(CMnDataCachePoolMgr.java:537)
com.bp.dw.sales.datacache.pool.CMnDataCachePoolMgr.initiateIncrementalCache(CMnDataCachePoolMgr.java:466)
com.bp.dw.sales.datacache.pool.CMnDataCachePoolMgr.initiateIncrementalCache(CMnDataCachePoolMgr.java:461)
com.bp.dw.sales.datacache.pool.CMnDataCachePoolMgr.initiateIncrementalCache(CMnDataCachePoolMgr.java:456)
com.bp.dw.sales.datacache.pool.CMnDataCachePoolMgr.initiateIncrementalCache(CMnDataCachePoolMgr.java:451)
com.ac.gp.wb.CMnWorkbookWizardComp.actionFinishHook(CMnWorkbookWizardComp.java:367)
com.ui.wizard.CMnWizardComp$4.actionPerformed(CMnWizardComp.java:500)
com.ui.fw.CMnBaseWidgetComp.fireActionListeners(CMnBaseWidgetComp.java:699)
com.ui.fw.CMnBaseRequestComp.fireActionListeners(CMnBaseRequestComp.java:422)
com.ui.fw.CMnBaseWidgetComp$1.clientEvent(CMnBaseWidgetComp.java:92)
com.ui.fw.client.CMnFormClientEventDispatcher.dispatch(CMnFormClientEventDispatcher.java:97)
... 22 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bp.gp.addfilters.CMnAddQueryConverter from [Module "deployment.pharma.ear.pharma.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
... 41 more
```

I have jaxb-api.jar, jaxb-impl.jar and jaxb-xjc.jar getting loaded from code but not from JBoss default modules as they are getting used in my code.

Any pointer for the possible cause of this exception?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two folder with same name in different case and hence the issue.

My EAR had folder structure like: 
com.bp.gp.addfilters and com.bp.gp.addFilters.

Looks like, JBoss uses underlying OS's search method to look for folder.

Linux search is case sensitive by default, hence it never gave this error.

Since windows search is case insensitive by default, it was always trying to search inside com.bp.gp.addFilters package whereas the class was present in com.bp.gp.addfilters package.